# Why does a Lucene fuzzy search with non-latin text result in a TooComplexToDeterminizeException more easily?

Tags: java, lucene, internationalization

I have the following test case where I perform a fuzzy query. Both cases insert some "Lorem Ipsum" text, but one is in the Latin alphabet whereas the other one uses the Cyrillic one.

However, the Cyrillic test case throws an exception

> org.apache.lucene.util.automaton.TooComplexToDeterminizeException:
>   Determinizing automaton with 34479 states and 58454 transitions would result in more than 10000 states.

while the Latin one does not, even though it consists of a lot more characters and words.

If I reduce the maximum edit distance for the Cyrillic case to `1`, it works fine. But I am wondering why that issue manifests in the first place for one alphabet but not the other. I have also noticed similar behavior with other alphabets like Devanagari.

Is there something I can do to avoid these issues regardless of the input language but while still keeping a maximum edit distance of `2`?

The test is written with JUnit 4.12 and Lucene Core + Common Analyzers 8.3.0.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.ru.RussianAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause.Occur;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.FuzzyQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LuceneTest
{
  private static final String ID_FIELD = "ID";
  private static final String NAME_FIELD = "NAME";

  @Test
  public void testLatin() throws IOException
  {
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

    String latin = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, has ex bonorum scripserit,"
        + " graeco volutpat aliquando ut eum, nec partem evertitur maiestatis ea."
        + " Ad vim aliquam dignissim. Eu audire delectus eum, vel eu viderer democritum voluptatum."
        + " Eu ludus utinam fabulas vim, mei te accumsan conceptam, at sea possit aperiam tacimates."
        + " Sed periculis repudiare ut."
        + " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, has ex bonorum scripserit,"
        + " graeco volutpat aliquando ut eum, nec partem evertitur maiestatis ea."
        + " Ad vim aliquam dignissim. Eu audire delectus eum, vel eu viderer democritum voluptatum."
        + " Eu ludus utinam fabulas vim, mei te accumsan conceptam, at sea possit aperiam tacimates."
        + " Sed periculis repudiare ut.";

    // This completes successfully.
    runLuceneTest( latin, latin, analyzer, 2 );
  }

  @Test
  public void testCyrillic() throws IOException
  {
    Analyzer analyzer = new RussianAnalyzer();

    String cyrillic = "Лорем ипсум долор сит амет, елитр ностер дисцере цу нам, ет вих мунере лаборес феугаит."
        + " Фалли делицатиссими усу еа, еа ферри солеат диссентиет ест, новум лаудем усу еу."
        + " Цу при малис путент мнесарчум.";

    // This throws an execption with edit distance 2.
    runLuceneTest( cyrillic, cyrillic, analyzer, 2 );
  }

  private void runLuceneTest( String insertText, String searchText, Analyzer analyzer, int maxEditDistance )
      throws IOException
  {
    Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig( analyzer );

    try ( IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter( index, config ) )
    {
      w.addDocument( createDoc( 42, insertText ) );
      w.commit();
    }

    List<Document> result = search( index, searchText, maxEditDistance );
    assertEquals( "Number of results", 1, result.size() );
    assertEquals( "Document ID", 42, Integer.parseInt( result.get( 0 ).getField( ID_FIELD ).stringValue() ) );
  }

  private Document createDoc( long id, String name )
  {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add( new TextField( ID_FIELD, Long.toString( id ), Store.YES ) );
    doc.add( new StringField( NAME_FIELD, name, Store.NO ) );
    return doc;
  }

  private List<Document> search( Directory index, String name, int maxEditDistance ) throws IOException
  {
    BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    builder.add( new FuzzyQuery( new Term( NAME_FIELD, name ), maxEditDistance ), Occur.SHOULD );
    BooleanQuery query = builder.build();

    int maxHits = 50;
    try ( IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open( index ) )
    {
      IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher( reader );
      TopDocs docs = searcher.search( query, maxHits );
      ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;
      List<Document> result = new ArrayList<>();
      for ( ScoreDoc hit : hits )
      {
        result.add( searcher.doc( hit.doc ) );
      }
      return result;
    }
  }

}
```